# Why does this code not return the temperature information that I am looking for?

Tags: python, regex

```
def temperature():
    r = requests.get('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/b02b5107a2c9c27deaa3bc1876bcee81/1.312914,%20103.780257')
    json_object = r.text

    regexCurrentTemp = re.compile(r'"temperature":(\d\d.\d\d)')
    moTemp = regexCurrentTemp.search(str(json_object))

    regexApparentTemp = re.compile(r'"apparentTemperature":(\d\d.\d\d)')
    moApparent = regexApparentTemp.search(str(json_object))

    print('The current temperature is %s and the apparent temperature is %s' % (moTemp.group, moApparent.group))

temperature()
```

When I remove the `.group`s from `print('The current temperature is %s and the apparent temperature is %s' % (moTemp.group, moApparent.group))`, it prints a highly unformatted string for me.

Edit:

With `.group`:
`The current temperature is <re.Match object; span=(662, 681), match='"temperature":85.87'> and the apparent temperature is <re.Match object; span=(239, 266), match='"apparentTemperature":99.26'>`

Without `.group`:

`The current temperature is <built-in method group of re.Match object at 0x75ab9560> and the apparent temperature is <built-in method group of re.Match object at 0x75ab95`

Comment: Please show the output you receive

Comment: [`group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) is a method of the [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). So you need to call `moTemp.group()`, `moApparent.group()` instead of `moTemp.group, moApparent.group`

Comment: I do one project away from Pycharm, and I am an idiot and forget this. I am sorry about that. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `group(subgroup)` to print the actual value of the match. Check out the [documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group)

```
print('The current temperature is %s and the apparent temperature is %s' % (moTemp.group(1), moApparent.group(1)))

#The current temperature is 86.53 and the apparent temperature is 98.18

.group(0) or .group() returns: 

#The current temperature is "temperature":86.55 and the apparent temperature is "apparentTemperature":99.33
```